# CSS, REACT: Cannot position siblings on one line;

Tags: css, reactjs

[what I want vs what i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enrIB.png)

Please look at the drawing I attached, as I cannot share original screenshot of what I have.

This is my React code for that "li" element:

```
import { Typography } from "@material-ui/core";
...
const { subscriptions } = useContext(SubscriptionsContext);
...
    const renderSubscriptionLinks = () => {
      return (<S.List>{subscriptionsList.map((el : SubscriptionDescription) => (
    <S.LinkContainer key={el.name}><div><S.LinkStyled href="google.com"><Typography variant="body2">{el.name + "  "}</Typography></S.LinkStyled> - <S.BestFor variant="body3">{el.bestFor + "  "}</S.BestFor></div></S.LinkContainer>
  ))}</S.List>);
```

};

Styled components' code:

```
export const LinkStyled = styled("a")`
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    margin-right: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(0.25)};
    ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
            margin-right: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(0.5)};
    }
    p { font-weight: 600; }
`
export const LinkContainer = styled("li")`
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 40px;
    &:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(1)}; }
    ::marker {
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
        &:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(2)}; min-height: unset; }
    }
    div {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      font-size: 14px;
      align-items: center;
      position: relative;
      top: -3px;
      color: black;
    }
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.red};
`
export const BestFor = styled(Typography)`
    margin-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(0.25)};
    ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
        margin-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(0.5)};
    }
`
export const List = styled("ul")`
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 904px;
  margin-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(3)};
  ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
      margin-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(8.75)};
  }
`;
```

I have a subscriptions description page, data is from API.

To reproduce, please just do the following:

```
function Subscriptions () {
  return (<>
<S.List><S.LinkContainer key={0}><div><S.LinkStyled href="google.com"><Typography variant="body2">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</Typography></S.LinkStyled> - <S.BestFor variant="body3">Ipsum ipsum ipsum</S.BestFor></div></S.LinkContainer>
<S.LinkContainer key={0}><div><S.LinkStyled href="google.com"><Typography variant="body2">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</Typography></S.LinkStyled> - <S.BestFor variant="body3">Ipsum ipsum ipsum</S.BestFor></div></S.LinkContainer>
<S.LinkContainer key={0}><div><S.LinkStyled href="google.com"><Typography variant="body2">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</Typography></S.LinkStyled> - <S.BestFor variant="body3">Ipsum ipsum ipsum</S.BestFor></div></S.LinkContainer>
<S.LinkContainer key={0}><div><S.LinkStyled href="google.com"><Typography variant="body2">Lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem lorem</Typography></S.LinkStyled> - <S.BestFor variant="body3">Ipsum ipsum ipsum</S.BestFor></div></S.LinkContainer>
      </S.List>
</>)
}
```

In Devtools I see that LinkStyled ("a" element) is full width of the outer container, and that is why it doesn't let its siblings to go on the same line as it is on, even though there is only one word on the next line which is a full width one.

Comment: It looks like `<S.LinkContainer>` is part of something  larger that is looping through and rendering the list items. Could you please modify the code that you have provided in a way that will be functional for someone who doesn't have any additional context about your project. 

For a better idea of what I'm talking about please see the article ["How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @Brice, Thanks for your comment, I'll update it right now

Comment: I've updated the question so that it renders static data

Comment: what is `theme`

Comment: I'm sure this is a simple CSS issue and does not stem from your use of react, styled-components, etc. 

Could you perhaps provided the rendered HTML w/ the relevant styles?

Comment: I'm sorry for late answering, Brice, I've already solved the issue just a few minutes ago, I will post the answer below if anyone else will have such a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<S.LinkContainer key={el.name}><div><S.LinkStyled href="google.com"><Typography variant="body2">{el.name + "  "}</Typography></S.LinkStyled> - <S.BestFor variant="body3">{el.bestFor + "  "}</S.BestFor></div></S.LinkContainer>
```

to

```
 <S.LinkContainer key={el.name}><span><S.LinkStyled href="google.com"><Typography variant="body2">{el.name}</Typography></S.LinkStyled> - <S.BestFor variant="body3">{el.bestFor}</S.BestFor></span></S.LinkContainer>
```

And styled components will change respectively to:

```
export const LinkStyled = styled("a")`
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    display: inline;
    margin-right: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(0.25)};
    ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
            margin-right: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(0.5)};
    }
    p { font-weight: 600; display: inline; }
`
export const LinkContainer = styled("li")`
    padding: 0;
    min-height: 40px;
    width: 80vw;
    white-space: break-spaces;
    &:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(1)}; }
    ::marker {
      font-size: 25px;
    }
    ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
        &:not(:last-child) { margin-bottom: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(2)}; min-height: unset; }
    }
    > span {
      width: 80vw;
      font-size: 14px;
      align-items: center;
      display: contents;
      position: relative;
      top: -3px;
      color: black;
      @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        top: -25px;
      }
    }
    box-sizing: content-box;
    color: ${({ theme }) => theme.palette.primaryOrange.main};
`
export const BestFor = styled(Typography)`
    margin-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(0.25)};
    ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
        margin-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(0.5)};
    }
`
export const List = styled("ul")`
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  max-width: 904px;
  margin-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(3)};
  ${({ theme }) => theme.breakpoints.up('md')} {
      margin-left: ${({ theme }) => theme.spacing(8.75)};
  }
`;
```

The thing causing this issue was display: flex for the `<span>` element, not sure why it didn't work, but I anyways solved it just replacing with equivalent properties that gave the expected result even without the `display: flex` :)